# Showlabels notes typeset flush left

Tags: showlabels

I use the `showlabels` package with the option `[inline]` by invoking it with the command

```
\usepackage[inline]{showlabels}
```

In this case the notes corresponding to the labels of environments (like theorems etc.) or to the command `\bibitem` (if I use `\showlabels{bibitem}`) are typeset flush **right**. Is there a way to change this behaviour and to typeset them flush **left** instead?

EDIT Here is a minimal working example: thmlabel, biblabel1, biblabel2 are flush right, whereas I want them to be flush left (as marked in red on the picture below).

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{biblabel1,
  author = {Author1, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title1},
  publisher = {Publisher1},
}
@book{biblabel2,
  author = {Author2, A.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Title2},
  publisher = {Publisher2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[inline]{showlabels}

\showlabels{ref}
\showlabels{cite}
\showlabels{bibitem}

\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm} \label{thmlabel}
Theorem text with equation
\begin{equation} \label{eqlabel}
x^2+y^2=z^2
\end{equation}
\end{thm}

Here are Theorem~\ref{thmlabel}, equation \eqref{eqlabel}, and two bibliography items authored by Author1 \cite{biblabel1} and by Author2 \cite{biblabel2}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can take control over the way that labels are formatted by redefining `\showlabelsetlabel`.  There's an example in the documentation, but you might try (untested)

```
\renewcommand{\showlabelsetlabel}[1]
  {\hbox to 0pt{\hss\showlabelfont #1}}
```

If that's not what you're looking for, then a minimal-working-example might be useful.

Comment: Many thanks! Alas, this not what I had in mind. An MWE has been added.